# Riemann–Hilbert-type problem

Tags: cv.complex-variables, modular-forms, percolation

Let $P$ be a fixed pentagon in the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H^2$ with all the angles equal to $\pi / 3$. Let $w_1, w_2, \dots, w_5$ be the sides
of $P$ going in the counterclockwise order. We are looking for five holomorphic 
functions $f_1, f_2, \dots f_5 \colon \mathbb H^2 \to \mathbb C$ such that $\sum_{j=1}^5  f_j(z) \equiv 1$ and if $z \in w_j$ for some $j$ then the following numbers are real

$$f_j(z),\quad 
\tau f_{j+1} (z),\quad 
\overline \tau f_{j-1} (z),\quad 
f_{j+1}(z) + f_{j-2}(z), \quad
f_{j-1}(z) + f_{j+2}(z) \in \mathbb R,$$
where $\tau = \exp(2\pi i / 3)$. Is it true that the space of solutions $(f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5)$ has finite dimension? Is it true that there is at most one solution?

[image: image of pentagon in the hyperbolic plane]

Comment: I am confused with your notation. You say $z\in\{ w_j\}$ and the following statements depend on $j$. Can we remove the curly braces?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko , thanks, I've corrected the question. 
I meant that the given condition holds for any $j$. 
The curly brackets were added by j.c. , I hope he doesn't mind I have removed them.

Comment: The function $g=f_1^3$ satisfies $g(Tz)=\overline{g(z)}$, where $T$ is a symmetry in $w_1,w_2$ or $w_5$. Thus the group generated by these three symmetries must be discrete, else $f_1\equiv 0$ which quickly yields a contradiction. This looks a rare event (say, if $w_2$ and $w_5$ intersect at a point belonging to $\mathbb{H}^2$ and the angle between them is not a rational multiple of $\pi$, the composition of symmetries w.r.t. them already generates a non-discrete group.)

Comment: @FedorPetrov , 1) Those symmetries belong to the symmetry group of the corresponding tessellation of $\mathbb H^2$ wich seems to be discrete.

<br><br>
2) Let us suppose that lines  $w_1, w_2, w_5$ form a triangle $T$. If $T$ lies "below" $w_1$ then it has
angles $(2\pi/3, 2\pi/3, \dots)$, so its area is negative. If $T$ lies "above" $w_1$ then it has
angles $(\pi/3, \pi/3, \dots)$, so its area is at most $\pi/3$ and the pentagon $P$ of area
$3\pi-5\pi/3 = \frac43\pi$ can not fit inside $T$. So I think the sad fact is that $w_2$, $w_5$
can not intersect each other.

Comment: @Misha is it discrete for any equiangular pentagon? Or for generic? Why? Well, they do not intersect of course indeed, but I guess the composition of two symmetries is in general an element of infinite order even when it is not a rotation.

Comment: @FedorPetrov , 1) I think starting from generic $P$ with angles of form $\pi/n$ and by flipping it along the edges one can construct a tessellation of $\mathbb H^2$. 

  2) In the case they do not intersect the composition is hyperbolic (e.g. $z\mapsto 2z$ in the upper half-plane). So the generated group is infinite but still discrete.

Comment: @Misha there will be no overlap? is it obvious? (sorry for my ignorance)

Comment: @FedorPetrov Seemed not obvious to me, too; what comes to my mind is to take a regular $P_0$ and the associated tesselation of $H^2$, and then change the Riemannian metric on it by taking the flips of the (-1) curvature metric cut out from $P$ itself (with its lengths). What we get is a conformal structure+Riemannian metric of curvature (-1), quasi-isometric to $H$, thus isometric to $H$. Pushing forward the initial tesselation we get a new one. Hope that helps...

Comment: UPD: Yes, the dimension of the space of solutions is finite; that follows e.g. from (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120033/why-are-the-holomorphic-line-bundle-sections-finite-dimensional). It is still very interesting if the solution is unique.