# Dimension of global holomorphic sections of a line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces, sheaf-cohomology, line-bundles, meromorphic-functions

Let $K$ be the canonical line bundle of a compact Riemann surface $M$ of genus $g$. Consider the pull back of $K$ on $M \times M$ *via* projection on the first factor. What is the dimension of the space of global holomorphic sections of this pull back line bundle on $M \times M$?

I can calculate its Euler characteristic by Riemann–Roch (Noether’s formula), but how does one calculate $H^0$?

Comment: By the Kunneth formula: $H^0(M\times M,K\boxtimes \mathscr{O}_M)=H^0(M,K)\otimes H^0(M,\mathscr{O}_M)$ $\cong H^0(M,K)$, hence the dimension is $g$.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120033/why-are-the-holomorphic-line-bundle-sections-finite-dimensional/120170#120170